# C# Bot Framework : Form flow set value for the field based on previous Answer

Tags: bots, botframework

I am trying to achieve two condition:

1) If user select Device Id value as 'Other Device', then Device Name prompt should appear (user have to enter value for Device Name).

2) If user select some other value for Device Id, then that selected value should automatically assign to DeviceName field and user dont need to enter value for that question (question 2 should skip and move to the final question).
**Model:**

```
public class ITRequestQuery
{
    [Optional]
    [Template(TemplateUsage.NoPreference, "Other Device")]
    public string DeviceID { get;  set; }
    [Prompt("Enter Device Name")]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    [Prompt("Please explain me more about your request! I will forward it to our IT Team.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

**Method**

```
return new FormBuilder<ITRequestQuery>()
            .Field(new FieldReflector<ITRequestQuery>(nameof(ITRequestQuery.DeviceID))
            .SetActive((state) =>
            {
                return assetID != null && assetID.Count > 0;
            })
            .SetType(null)
            .SetDefine((state, field) =>
            {
                foreach (var prod in AssetIds())
                    field
                        .AddDescription(prod, prod)
                        .AddTerms(prod, prod);
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<ITRequestQuery>(nameof(ITRequestQuery.DeviceName))
            .SetActive((state1)=> {
                if (state1.DeviceID == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
                }
            ))
            .Field(nameof(ITRequestQuery.Description))
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Build();
```

I stuck over here,

```
if (state1.DeviceID == null)
                    return true;
```

actually,this condition should show 2nd question but its again going to 1st question.

Comment: @EzequielJadib I want to setValue to the 2nd question. On both condition i have to capture value for 2nd question. 1) Automatically(based on 1st answer) 2) by user.

Comment: Yes. Take a look to the answer to the other question, something really similar is being done. The key is the SetNext